# Comparing values in Custom Validator in Angular

Tags: angular, validation, numbers, compare, undefined

I'm trying to compare two input values in a custom validator. There should be an error if the minValue is greater than the maxValue.

FormGroup:

```
    sumFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
     from: ['', [Validators.min(0), sumValidator]],
     to: ['', [Validators.min(0), sumValidator]]
  });
```

custom validator:

```
 function sumValidator (control: AbstractControl):{[key: string]: boolean} | null {
   let minValue = control.get(this.sumFormGroup.get('from')).value;
   let maxValue = control.get(this.sumFormGroup.get('to')).value;
   if(minValue != maxValue){
    return {'ageValidator': true}
  }
  return null;
};
```

Error in browser console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sumFormGroup' of undefined
    at sumValidator in bla.ts
    (...)
```

Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: Since this function starts with `function`, `this.` does not refer to the class the function is defined in. That being said, are the other controls within the same form?

Comment: What other controls do you mean? I'm a beginner in angular, sorry. I don't know exactly what you mean

Comment: remove the function keyword from your `sumValidator` function

Comment: What should I do instead? It won't find sumValidator anymore -> "Cannot find name 'sumValidator'"

Comment: While calling the function you would use `this.sumValidator`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the validation 'more' pure would help.
Also I would suggest making two validations for this one.

```
function smallerThan(otherControlName: string) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if (!control.parent) {
            return null; // Control is not yet associated with a parent.
        }
        const thisValue = control.value;
        const otherValue = control.parent.get(otherControlName).value;
        if (thisValue < otherValue) {
            return null;
        }

        return {
            'smallerthan': true
        }
    };
}

function greaterThan(otherControlName: string) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if (!control.parent) {
            return null; // Control is not yet associated with a parent.
        }
        const thisValue = control.value;
        const otherValue = control.parent.get(otherControlName).value;
        if (thisValue > otherValue) {
            return null;
        }

        return {
            'greaterthan': true
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
sumFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    from: ['', [Validators.min(0), smallerThan('to')]],
    to: ['', [Validators.min(0), greaterThan('from')]]
 });
```

Perhaps you also need to take into account that the values may not be equal, but you could easily create two more validators called `smallerThanOrEquals` and `greaterThanOrEquals`.

If you wish to sync the validations, you could try to do it in the following way in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Example in the init, but make sure this.sumFormGroup is already created. 
    this.sumFormGroup.get('from').valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.sumFormGroup.get('to').updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false }));
    this.sumFormGroup.get('to').valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.sumFormGroup.get('from').updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I am still getting that error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: @pokly Are you referring to `....parent.get(...)`? If so, Perhaps the validator is run before the form is associated. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes it's the parent.get(...). Thank you so much!

Comment: Excuse me, do you have an idea how I can "update" each input field after entering a new value into the other input field? Example: 
-minValue input: 10
-maxValue input: 5 (-> Validator shows error for the maxValue input, because its too low)
- I delete the "5", but the maxValue field with the "null" is still showing the error.

I would like to update it dynamically. When I delete the "wrong" number, the error should be gone

Comment: @pokly Check out my latest update. You could also use a single validator on the entire form, but that would also require you to manually refresh the validation I guess.

Comment: It's working, you're a hero I guess. Would like to give you more points and selected answers